# Как получить доступ к массиву через строку в PHP?

Tags: php

Есть структура на Яндекс.Диске, которая описана в массиве:

```
private $dirrectory = [
        'brandbook' => [],
        'source' => [
            'icons' => [
                'blue' => [
                    'svg' => [
                        'test'
                    ],
                ],
                'white' => [
                    'svg' => [],
                ],
            ],
            'illustrations' => [
                'blue' => [
                    'svg' => [],
                ],
                'white' => [
                    'svg' => [],
                ],
            ],
            'pictograms' => [
                'blue' => [
                    'svg' => [],
                ],
                'white' => [
                    'svg' => [],
                ],
            ],
            'templates' => []
        ],
        'upload' => [],

    ]; // Структура папок на яндекс диске (без папок png)
```

И мне нужно каким-то образом через строчку `"source/icons/blue/svg"` получить `$this->dirrectory['source']['icons']['blue']['svg']`, чтобы я мог туда записывать нужные мне данные.

У меня в голове был вариант в начале парсить строку (`explode('/', $path)`), а потом записывать распарсенные данные в такой вид `string`: `"['source']['icons']['blue']['svg']"`, и после всех этих действий сделать что-то вроде: `${"this->dirrectory['source']['icons']['blue']['svg']"}`, но как я выяснил в последствии это так не работает, а как правильно искать как это сделать я, увы, не знаю.

Может есть какая-нибудь библиотека, которая может из строки обратиться к массиву? Или же это можно сделать из под коробки `Lumen`?

Comment: подобное есть в helpers laravel data_get https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/8.x/src/Illuminate/Collections Только нужно сначала заменить / на . в строки и обратиться как вам нужно.

Comment: @OlegDmitrochenko, Кажется это то что я искал, сейчас опробую

Comment: explode и тупо в цикле. задачка для первого класса

Comment: @Ипатьев что именно в "тупо в цикле"?

Comment: в цикле перебирать ключи и обращаться к элементам массива. $array = dirrectory['source'] дает тебе первый элемент, и так далее, пока ключи в массиве не кончатся